Why doesn't OpenSSL use Karatsuba multiplication with bit extension when the numbers are of different sizes?
In the second paragraph of section 2.5 of the  paper Remote Timing Attacks are Practical the authors write:

When $g$ is just below a multiple of $q$, then OpenSSL almost always uses fast Karatsuba multiplication. When $g$ is just over a multiple of $q$ then $g \bmod q$ is small and consequently most multiplications will be of integers with different lengths. Therefore, OpenSSL uses normal multiplication which is slower.

I am trying to understand exactly which multiplication the authors are writing about. Is there a reason why OpenSSL would not use Karatsuba in all cases?
If the integers are of different lengths, why not just pad the smaller one with zeros to get two numbers of the same length. Karatsuba should be able to work with numbers that start with 0. In fact, it might even be faster to calculate if half of a number is 0. If the claim is that Karatsuba is faster than the standard multiplication (therefore revealing some timing difference), then shouldn't padding with zeros be the simplest and best solution?

As far as I remember, the choice was to make the operations constant time bluntly

@kelalaka as per the paper, the operations are not constant time, thereby leading to the side channel

They do simple analyze, that is why they got attacks all the time

This is almost a canned comment by now, but "why" questions are notoriously hard to answer. I would rather try and connect to the OpenSSL devs and ask them. If you are able to reach them then please also share the solution here, or even better, ask them to post an answer. Also bump :)
